# Rails 5 requires initializer in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app requires some pre-computation on initialize. I have a Ruby file `config/initializers/start_1.rb`, and in this file, I `require` a generic module in `/config/lib/init_module.rb` as below:

```
require './lib/init_module.rb'
Init::Class1.new
Init::Class1.new
```

In `/config/lib/init_module.rb` file, I increment a value for every new object as below:

```
module Init
  class Class1
    @@local = 0

    def initialize
      @@local += 1
    end

    def self.local
      @@local
    end
  end
end
```

In my application controller, for each request from the client, I want to use this pre-computed value.

1. If I `require /config/lib/init_module.rb` in my application controller, it will give me nothing (= `0`) about the local value as every request will create a new instance. (Actually, I don't understand why `@@local` is a class variable.)
2. If I `require /config/initializers/start_1.rb` in my application controller, it will run the initializer for every request, which will result in a huge overhead.

I would appreciate your suggestions for my problem.

Comment: So you basically need to use `@@local` value in your controller, right?

Comment: yes, basically I do use @@local in controller

Comment: It would help to understand the bigger picture, because depending on what you're trying to accomplish, this approach might not work in an environment with multiple Rails processes or in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using .pow server to give local domain name to my apps and the problem was to let .pow server to reload for every requests, after deleting tmp/restart.txt from my app, the problem solved! Thanks for the helps.