# rails config/initializers are executed for every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails app needs initializers which I put them in config/initializers folder. I need them to run for once and only in the beginning namely when the server starts, but rails execute them for each request coming from client side. So, every time a controller is called all of the initializers are executed by rails. I work in the development environment. This is how development.rb looks like:

```
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

Any ideas?

A sample init file:

```
module Constants 

    GPK_window_size = 256


    Key_path = "./some_path"

    def self.gpk_window_size
        return GPK_window_size 
    end

end

Rails.logger.debug "Constants file executed.."
```

Comment: How do you tell they are run for every request?

Comment: I put Rails.logger.debug in those files and tail the log and I see it's executed every time

Comment: Could you show an example of such file?

Comment: I updated the issue

Comment: Can you confirm that the https://github.com/guard/listen gem is installed? Have you tried changing `file_watcher` back to the default `ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`?

Comment: The problem was related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895206/rails-5-requires-initializer-in-application-controller. Thanks for your comments.